# jQuery/Javascript code not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add table rows dynamically using jQuery/Javascript and I have used the following code but it's not working in Chrome. Any help?

```
function AddTextBoxes(label,parameter, paraId) {
  strCode += "<tr><td>";
  strCode += "<label id='" + label + "1'>" + label + "</label></td><td>";
  strCode += "<input type='text' id=" + paraId +" value="+parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue+ ">";
  $("#" + paraId).attr('value', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
  $("#" + paraId).attr('text', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
  strCode += "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Have you declared `var strCode = ''` outside of the function?

Comment: You need to append the contents of strcode.

Comment: @Geek This function only creates a string with some HTML in it, what exactly means "it doesn't work" in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the contents of strcode which you are not doing in your function.

Also:-

You need to add  `var strCode = ''`  before this line(At the beginning of the function):-

```
strCode += "<tr><td>";
```

Comment: Actually my code is working fine in IE but not in chrome or Mozilla.I have added strCode to my div using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with needed modifications. Also, you need to do somethign with the resulting string. For example append it to body. (untested)

```
function AddTextBoxes(label,parameter, paraId) {
  var strCode = "<tr><td>";
  strCode += "<label id='" + label + "1'>" + label + "</label></td><td>";
  strCode += "<input type='text' id=" + paraId +" value="+parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue+ ">";
  $("#" + paraId).attr('value', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
  $("#" + paraId).attr('text', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
  strCode += "</td></tr>";
  document.body.innerHTML += strCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `strCode` and `append` it to `table`. Example

```
$('#tableId').append(strCode);
```

Updated Code:

```
function AddTextBoxes(label, parameter, paraId) {
    var strCode = '';
    strCode += "<tr><td>";
    strCode += "<label id='" + label + "1'>" + label + "</label></td><td>";
    strCode += "<input type='text' id=" + paraId + " value=" + parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue + ">";
    $("#" + paraId).attr('value', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
    $("#" + paraId).attr('text', parameter.minValue + "-" + parameter.maxValue);
    strCode += "</td></tr>";

    $('#tableId').append(strCode); // Change tableId with your table id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myRow="<tr><td>my row</td></tr>";
$("#myTableId").append(myRow);
```